# Stored procedure to get cutomer Ids on the basis of comma seperated value passed

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, relational-division

Items Table:

| id | item_name | code | cust_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mango | 111 | u1 |
| 2 | Milk | 112 | u2 |
| 3 | Chocolate | 113 | u3 |
| 4 | Milk | 112 | u1 |
| 5 | Mango | 111 | u2 |
| 6 | Berry | 114 | u3 |
| 7 | Chocolate | 113 | u1 |
| 8 | Berry | 114 | u2 |
| 9 | Ice-cream | 114 | u3 |
| 10 | Mango | 111 | u4 |

These is the customer table and I have to write an **stored procedure** in SQL Server to find the cust_id who have buy all items passed in comma separated values like 'Mango,Milk,Chocolate'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Items_find
    @items_value nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
END

EXEC Items_find 'Mango,Milk,Chocolate'  
EXEC Items_find 'Mango,Milk'
```

Stored procedure should return `cust_id = u1` if `'Mango,Milk'`  then output should be `cust_id=u1, u2` or if `'Mango'` then output is `cust_id=u1, u2, u3`

I have tried to filter out the `cust_id` w.r.t. to the count of items passed in comma-separated but after that I am not able find the `cust_id` who buys specifically these items

Comment: does STRING_AGG() solve your problem?

Comment: Use [Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) to pass the values in

Comment: how about `where 'Mango, Milk' like '%' + item_name + '%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to count first how many words are in your search,
and then select all rows that contain your search and use the count to keep only those with the same group by count

Here is an example

```
declare @Items table (id int, item_name varchar(50), code int, cust_id varchar(10))
insert into @Items values (1, 'Mango', 111, 'u1'),
(2, 'Milk', 112, 'u2'), (3, 'Chocolate', 113, 'u3'), (4, 'Milk', 112, 'u1'), (5, 'Mango', 111, 'u2'),
(6, 'Berry', 114, 'u3'), (7, 'Chocolate', 113, 'u1'), (8, 'Berry', 114, 'u2'), (9, 'Ice-cream', 114, 'u3'),
(10, 'Mango', 111, 'u4')
```

```
declare @search varchar(50) = 'Mango,Milk'
declare @cnt int = (select len(@search) - len(replace(@search, ',', '')) + 1)

select cust_id
from   @Items
where  @search like '%' + item_name + '%'
group by cust_id
having count(1) = @cnt
```

this will return

```
cust_id
u1
u2
```

And if you want it in one string, you can use string_agg for that

```
declare @search varchar(50) = 'Mango,milk'
declare @cnt int = (select len(@search) - len(replace(@search, ',', '')) + 1)

select 'cust_id = ' +
( select string_agg(t.cust_id, ', ') 
          from   ( select top 100000
                          i.cust_id
                   from   @Items i
                   where @search like '%' + i.item_name + '%'
                   group by i.cust_id
                   having count(1) = @cnt
                  ) t
 ) as Result
```

this will return

```
cust_id = u1, u2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @InProducts VARCHAR(100);
--SET @InProducts='Mango,Milk,Chocolate';
SET @InProducts='Mango,Milk';

WITH CTE(id, item_name, code, cust_id) AS
(
  SELECT 1,'MANGO',111,'U1'
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,'MILK',112,'U2'
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,'CHOCOLATE',113,'U3'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,'MILK',112,'U1'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 5,'MANGO',111,'U2'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 6,'BERRY',114,'U3'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 7,'CHOCOLATE',113,'U1'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 8,'BERRY',114,'U2'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 9,'ICE-CREAM',115,'U3'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 10,'MANGO',111,'U4'
)
SELECT Z.CUST_ID FROM
 (
    SELECT C.*FROM CTE AS C
    JOIN string_split(@InProducts,',')X ON C.item_name=X.value
 )Z 
GROUP BY Z.cust_id HAVING COUNT(Z.CUST_ID)=
(
    SELECT COUNT(X.VALUE) FROM string_split(@InProducts,',')X
)
```

Hope, you can use something like this